# Sql code to calculate proportional value of a given value between two rows in a table

Tags: sql

I’m very new to SQL. I can only do excel macro.
I have tank volume table, which has id, height and volume as below

```
Id  Height  Volume
1     0          0
2     1       1000
3     2       1950
4     3       3050
5     4       4020  
6     5       5000
```

I need a sql code to calculate, proportional value when my actual tank height is 3.5.
Answer should be `(((4020-3050)/(4-3))*(3.5-3))+3050 = 3535`.

Comment: your question is not much clear, could you please describe a little bit more

Comment: From the above table, I want to calculate the corresponding volume, if my given height is 3.5.

Comment: What is your database (DBMS), please tag your question with it.

Answer (score 0):

No DBMS is given but this answer works for MySql and is based on so called Windows functions, hopefully it will work on other DBMS as well.

The inner subquery creates a table of height, height from previous row, volume and volume for previous row all on the same row. This then makes it possible to select the correct row and do a linear interpolation on volume based on the given height

```
SELECT DISTINCT ((volume - prev_volume)/(height - prev_height)) * (@given_height - prev_height) + prev_volume AS calculated_volume
FROM (SELECT height, 
             LAG(height, 1) OVER w AS prev_height,
             volume,
             LAG(volume, 1) OVER w AS prev_volume
      FROM volume
      WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY height ASC)) AS t
WHERE @given_height BETWEEN prev_height and height
```

Comment: @Gugan, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, that uses standard ANSI sql and does not rely on window functions, hence that should work on most RDBMS / versions.

The principle is to use subqueries to find the ids of the closest records around the given height, and the do the computation in the outer query. You would need to replace the `?` with the height for which you want to compute the volume.

```
SELECT
    (tsup.volume - tinf.volume)
        / (tsup.height - tinf.height)
        * (? - tinf.height) 
        + tinf.volume
    as regression
FROM
    (
        SELECT t.*
        FROM mytable t
        WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM mytable WHERE height > ?) 
    ) tsup
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT t.*
        FROM mytable t
        WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable WHERE height < ?)
    ) tinf
```

Here is [a MySQL 5.7 DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qGMCyYRQnr4jTh3ppW2L9L/1) :

```
SET @search = 3.5;

SELECT
    (tsup.volume - tinf.volume)/(tsup.height - tinf.height)*(@search - tinf.height) + tinf.volume regression
FROM
    (
        SELECT t.*
        FROM mytable t
        WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM mytable WHERE height > @search) 
    ) tsup
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT t.*
        FROM mytable t
        WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable WHERE height < @search)
    ) tinf;
```

```
| regression |
| ---------- |
| 3535       |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works well with slight modification of height '>='.

Comment: @Gugan : welcome ! If you believe that my answer properly responded to your question, please consider accepting it... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You want the next smallest and biggest values.  You can get this using:

```
(select t.*
 from t
 where t.height <= 3.5
 order by t.height desc
 fetch first 1 row only
) union all
(select t.*
 from t
 where t.height >= 3.5
 order by t.height asc
 fetch first 1 row only
)
```

With this information, you can do the calculation you want:

```
select (case when min(height) = max(height) 
 -- exact match
             then min(volume)
             else (min(volume +
                   (max(volume) - min(volume)) / (max(height - min(height)) * (3.5 - min(height)
                 )
        end) as interpolated_volume
from ((select t.*
       from t
       where t.height <= 3.5
       order by t.height desc
       fetch first 1 row only
      ) union all
      (select t.*
       from t
       where t.height >= 3.5
       order by t.height asc
       fetch first 1 row only
      ) 
     ) t;
```

This assumes that volume is increasing with height -- which seems very reasonable in this situation.  It is possible to adjust this code for other situation.

Note that this uses standard SQL syntax elements.  Some databases have slightly varying syntax.